# Drilling down into JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

This is a really simple task, that has me absolutely stumped! I'm pulling back some JSON via CURL and PHP, and attempting to access the data from the below structure:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'maxResults' => int 43
  public 'resultList' => 
    array (size=43)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[2]
          public '@class' => string '' (length=64)
          public 'id' => int
          public 'version' => int 0
          public 'dateCreated' => string '2014-02-11T18:37:55.835+0000' (length=28)
          public 'dateModified' => null
          public 'locationId' => int
          public 'departmentId' => int
          public 'ownerCompanyId' => int
          public 'active' => boolean true
          public 'userId' => int
          public 'userName' => string '' (length=24)
          public 'externalCode' => null
          public 'employeeDetails' => 
            object(stdClass)[3]
              ...
          public 'chargeBandAllocationsIds' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
          public 'personalRateChargeBandId' => 
            object(stdClass)[13]
              ...
          public 'employeeGroupIds' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'isResource' => boolean false
```

(I've removed some of the values, for privacy reasons)

Now I'm trying to `var_dump` using `var_dump(json_decode($result, false));`, however when I try and get into the 'resultList' array using `var_dump(json_decode($result['resultList'], false));` I get an illegal string offset error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$result` is the JSON string, your cannot do `$result['resultList']` on a string. It only becomes a structure *after* you `json_decode` it. However, you're decoding it as *object*, not array, so this wouldn't work either way.

```
$data = json_decode($result);
var_dump($data->resultList);
var_dump($data->resultList[0]);
var_dump($data->resultList[0]->id);

foreach ($data->resultList as $employee) {
    var_dump($employee->id);
}
```